# C#, Linq, Entity Framework Combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, linq, combobox

I am currently having an issue I can't seem to resolve. I've created a method, where I pass in a combobox object, build a Linq Query and bind the ItemsSource to the result of the query. I have done this in VB.Net very successfully. In C# though When I debug the application and pulldown the combobox I'm seeing the following:
`System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.ReferenceGroup_FEA77E50BE7F55D3AD4A32EC3E42F6`
If I select the entry, then the correct DisplayPath and the Selected Value Path are working correctly. After selecting the above referenced the combobox displays "Address" which is correct.

LINQ Query:

```
    var source = (from g in adminEntities.ReferenceGroups
                  orderby g.ReferenceGroupName
                  select g);

   objSource.ItemsSource = source.ToList();
   return objSource;
```

ComboBox XAML Definition:

```
    <ComboBox Name="cboGroups" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" 
      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5"  
      SelectionChanged="cboGroups_SelectionChanged"
      DisplayMemberPath="ReferenceGroupName"
      SelectedValuePath="ReferenceGroupID"/>
```

This behavior is defferent between C# and VB.Net. Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: you are setting the ItemsSource of objSource and then returning it. What are you doing w/ it? The combo box has name cboGroups not objSource. Whats the relationship between objSource and cboGroups? Please create a minimum complete example

Comment: public ComboBox PopulateComboBox(ComboBox objSource, String dataSource)
        {
            try
            {
                var source = (from g in adminEntities.ReferenceGroups
                              orderby g.ReferenceGroupName
                              select g);
                objSource.ItemsSource = source.ToList();
                return objSource;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {            }
            return objSource;
        }

Comment: @user1756895: Comments are really not the place to paste code. Update the question.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out my issue. The displaying of the combobox entries is related to my WPF Theme and the Control Styling.